# Read through a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file that will contain details in order as below.

```
Name1
School Name1
State1
Name2
School Name2
State2
Name3
School Name3
State3
```

I want it to loop through 3 ( example file contains 3 sets, but I thought of logice(sic) here that if there are n sets, the loop should run for n sets) times and in first loop the file should be read from line1 to line3, then in next loop from line4 to line 6 , then from line 7 to line 9 and so on, if there are more entries in same set (Name,School Name,State). Upon each iteration it will feed the input from file to another standard output file. I have a working script that takes input from file and feeds it to another file, but finding it hard to get the logic if the set repeats.

Comment: So essentially you just want to move these records into another, more properly formatted file?  I'm sure someone can come up with a simple `awk` solution to do that.  Using a shell loop to process a file is not the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this to read a file 3 lines at a time:

```
while
    IFS= read -r name
    IFS= read -r school
    IFS= read -r state
do
    echo "$name:$school:$state"
done < input.file > output.file
```

Taking advantage of the fact that you can put many commands as the "condition" of a while loop.

Comment: here, `paste -d : - - - < input.file > output.file` would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and reproducing the exact same output as [glenn jackman does in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459373/116858):

```
$ awk -v OFS=':' '{ name=$0; getline sname; getline state;
                    print name,sname,state }' <input.file >output.file
```

The `-v OFS=':'` sets `OFS` (the "output field separator") to a colon.  The `getline` function in `awk` reads the next line (into the named variable), and `print` prints a record consisting of the given fields, separated by `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed '1~3{N;N;s/\n/:/g}' < input.file > output.file
```

How it works:

```
1~3        # match every 3rd line, starting with the 1st
{    
  N;N;     # append the next 2 lines of input into the pattern space
  s/\n/:/g # replace newlines with your chosen separator
}
```

Comment: `sed 'N;N;s/\n/:/g'` would be functionally equivalent and avoid the GNUism. But then again using the dedicated tool `paste -d : - - -` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs`,

```
xargs -d'\n' -n3 < file somecommand
```

will take groups of 3 newline-delimited values from `file` and pass them as arguments to `somecommand`

Ex. using `printf`:

```
$ xargs -d'\n' -n3 < file printf '"%s","%s","%s"\n'
"Name1","School Name1","State1"
"Name2","School Name2","State2"
"Name3","School Name3","State3"
```